# Folder writing permissions with php and plesk

Tags: php, file-permissions, plesk

Currently we are using centos 6.4 unfortunately i have used the following code:

```
if(@!mkdir("temp",0777)){
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo $error['message'];
```

which i get the error message `mkdir(): Permission denied`. we do use a dedicated server and we do use Plesk, Does anyone know how to give Apache permission to write files but also keeping the permissions for Plesk the same?

Comment: The parent folder permissions need fixing. In some instances we had to chown the parent folder to apache:apache before it was happy.

Comment: yes, i have used Chown before however Plesk was then unable to access the folder. I was looking for a more permanent solution without compromising security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to set the owner to the Plesk user, and the group to the user group that Apache belongs to. The permissions would then be 0775.

### Update

Each Unix service runs under a certain user account. For example, when using SuExec, my PHP files are owned by `myusername`, but the group is set to `www-data` (the user under which Apache runs). Since permissions are UGO (User, Group, Others), 775 would allow both me and the web server to write-access the files. Maybe the same idea can apply to Plesk.

Comment: can you explain as the answer is a little vague

Comment: i will accept as i did use this method with a combination of chmod and modgroup